# BeautifulSoup getText throwing an error

Tags: python, text, beautifulsoup, gettext

I'm trying to read the text from a web URL using the following code to store all valid strings to a variable which I can manipulate later. I am getting an error at run time though

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from django.template.defaultfilters import title

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.scotland.org/about-scotland/facts-about-scotland/')
data = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

textString = soup.findAll('p').getText()
print(textString)
```

error:

```
textString = soup.findAll('p').getText()
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'getText'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
textString = soup.findAll('p')[0].getText()
```

And if you want to get all `paragraph` data try this:

```
elements = soup.findAll('p')
for paragraph in elements:
    print paragraph.getText()
```

Comment: Ah this works, although only takes data from the first paragraph

Answer (score 0):

I got a work around. I guess the same idea as your edit, thanks!

```
textString = ""
for i in soup.find_all('p'):
    textString += i.getText()

print(textString)
```